# Is there a static constructor or static initializer in Python?

Tags: python

**Is there such a thing as a static constructor in Python?**

How do I implement a static constructor in Python?

Here is my code...  The `__init__` doesn't fire when I call App like this. The `__init__` is not a static constructor or static initializer.

```
App.EmailQueue.DoSomething()
```

I have to call it like this, which instantiates the App class every time:

```
App().EmailQueue.DoSomething()
```

Here is my class:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self._mailQueue = EmailQueue()

    @property
    def EmailQueue(self):
        return self._mailQueue
```

The problem with calling `__init__` every time is that the App object gets recreated.  My "real" App class is quite long.

Comment: Why don't you just put that code right after defining the class?  Or are you asking for lazy initialization?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hint: anything that references `self` is going to require an instantiation of the class. You could do it like this:

```
class App:
    email_queue = EmailQueue()

App.email_queue.do_something()
```

But come on, that seems like a lot of fluff. I'm with SLaks, just initialize it outside of the class. Alternatively, you could look into the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. it does not explain how to create a static initializer, instead it suggests to create objects.

Answer (score 31):

There's a fundamental difference between static and dynamic languages that isn't always apparent at first.

In a static language, the class is defined at compile time and everything is all nice and set in concrete before the program ever runs.

In a dynamic language, the class is actually defined at runtime.  As soon as the interpreter parses and starts executing all of those classes and def statements, the equivalent of a static constructor is being run.  The class definitions are being executed at that point.

You can put any number of statements anywhere inside the class body and they are in effect a static constructor.  If you want, you can place them all in a function that doesn't take `self` as a parameter, and call that function at the end of the class.

Comment: Have you actually tried `placing them all in a function that doesn't take self and at the end of the class call that  function`?  That isn't as straight-forward as it sounds because the class hasn't been created yet when that function runs.

Answer (score 29):

I create a `static_init` decorator which calls a `static_init` class method if it exists.

Here is the decorator and example of how to use it to initialize a class variable on an enum class:

```py
# pylint: disable=missing-docstring,no-member

import enum

def static_init(cls):
    if getattr(cls, "static_init", None):
        cls.static_init()
    return cls

@static_init
class SomeEnum(enum.Enum):
    VAL_A = enum.auto()
    VAL_B = enum.auto()
    VAL_C = enum.auto()
    VAL_D = enum.auto()

    @classmethod
    def static_init(cls):
        text_dict = {}
        setattr(cls, 'text_dict', text_dict)
        for value in cls:
            text_dict[value.name.lower().replace("_", " ").title()] = value

def test_static_init():
    assert SomeEnum.text_dict["Val A"] == SomeEnum.VAL_A
    assert SomeEnum.text_dict["Val B"] == SomeEnum.VAL_B
    assert SomeEnum.text_dict["Val C"] == SomeEnum.VAL_C
    assert SomeEnum.text_dict["Val D"] == SomeEnum.VAL_D
```

Comment: Glad to see answer that explicitly addresses the question. Nice solution too.

Comment: Slick solution.  Works great!  Just don't forget the "return cls" line in the first static_init() function.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `class` method - see `@classmethod` decorator in the the code sample bellow:

```
class A(object):
    _some_private_static_member = None

    @classmethod
    def reset_static_data_members(cls, some_value):
        cls._some_private_static_member = some_value

A.reset_static_data_members("some static value")
```

However, be aware, that this is most probably something you do **NOT** want to do, since it modifies state of **type** - so it will affect all further calls to methods of that type which use/depend-on the changed static class data members. Situation can get nasty if such static class data members are accessed & set via `self.` in instances of such class when you will easily get unexpected behaviour.

Really *correct way* to do this (or the common sense way which most developers expect that behavior will be), is to make sure the static data members will be set only **once** - during import (the analogical way static data member initialisation behave in C++, C#, Java). Python has mechanism for that- the **in-place** initialisation:

```
class A(object):
    _some_private_static_member_0 = "value 0"
    _some_private_static_member_1 = "value 1"
```

Potentially you can initialise the static class members with return values from functions which abstract out (of the class) more complex value generation:

```
class A(object):
    _some_private_static_member_0 = some_function_0()
    _some_private_static_member_1 = some_function_1()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your App, then use that instead:

```
myApp = App()
myApp.EmailQueue.DoSomething()
```

Comment: Good point. The OP did bemoan the fact that it gets instantiated "every time".

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on the matter, expounding on the region of code after the class def and before any class functions. I enclosed in an if condition as well as a code folding region so that various editors may be capable of folding this body of code in the event you wish to hide it....

```
class MyClass :

    myStaticVar1 = {}
    myStaticVar2 = []

    #region STATICINIT
    if not myStaticVar1 :
       # implement arbitrary initialization logic here
       # with any helper variables you don't want cluttering up the class
       localVarDontWantInClassScope = [1,2,3]

       myStaticVar1[0] = localVarDontWantInClassScope[0]
       myStaticVar1[1] = localVarDontWantInClassScope[2]

       myStaticVar2.append("abc")

       # local var cleanup
       del localVarDontWantInClassScope
    #endregion

    def f1(self, i) :
        print( "{} {}".format( i , MyClass.myStaticVar1[i] ) )
```