# Using a class without calling the constructor in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have simple class to fetch query from database .

```
# myClass.py
class DB:
    def __init__ (self, host, user, password):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","****","****","***")
        self.conn.set_character_set('utf8mb4')
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4;')
        cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;')
        cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;')
    def query(self, q):
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(q)
            return cursor
```

If I use the below query with it works ok,

```
from myClass import DB
q = DB("..", "..", "..", "..")
_fetch = q.query("... ")
```

However if I would like to get rid of the second line since I am declaring user, pass, host .. in myClass.py

So, when I try

```
from myClass import DB
_fetch = DB.query("... ")
```

it won't allow me to connect, even if I remove the `self,` keyword for query

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396092/is-there-a-static-constructor-or-static-initializer-in-python just call a method at class level

Comment: Look into using `@classmethod` decorator.

Comment: So why not just remove the arguments, and use `DB().query()`? Or create a  classmethod, and in that classmethod create the instance.

Comment: @KurtStutsman I added that method above ` def query` and I get `NameError: global name 'self' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
# myClass.py

# code will be executed only once a the first import 
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","****","****","***")
conn.set_character_set('utf8mb4')
cursor = conn.cursor()    
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4;')
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;')
cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;')

class DB:
    # class attribute shared among all DB instance
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # class method
    @classmethod
    def query(cls, q):
        cls.cursor.execute(q)
        return cursor
```

Comment: sorry but still does not work. I get no output from database. Not even a catchable error.

Comment: And what about @germn's response ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create class object ones and then just import and use it:

```
# myClass.py
class DB:
    def __init__ (self, host, user, password):
        # ...

db = DB("..", "..", "..", "..")  # Create object ones.
```

Somewhere in other module:

```
from myClass import db

db.query("... ")
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a good practice to add `db = DB('..')` at the end of `myClass.py` I would like to learn python the proper way and this seems a hack..

Comment: It's not a hack : https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/a-globals-class-pattern-for-python/

Comment: @ANW, it's not a hack. If you don't like it, only way I can advice is to remove params from init and make your DB class singleton. http://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/1113207

Comment: @germn I have spent 2 hours in this, it is like there is almost 0 ways it can work without some error. I even tried your solution and placed `db = DB()` in the last line of `myClass.py` but it still won't work.

Comment: @ANW Solution in my answer can't be reason. What happens after you created `db` and use it for queries?